# Jquery function works when I stop it with debugger, but not otherwise

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It's a tic tac toe game in JavaScript using jQuery. I can put "debugger" in after the winCondition function, and I get appropriate values for "winCondition" in the console (".top") but I can't get this function to work properly. Without "debugger" it returns and empty set ("[]") in console.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var move = "X",
        movestate = true,
        winCondition = [ 
        [".top", ".top", ".top"],
        [".mid", ".mid", ".mid"],
        [".bot", ".bot", ".bot"],
        [".l", ".l", ".l"],
        [".c", ".c", ".c"],
        [".r", ".r", ".r"],
        [".top, .l", ".mid, .c", ".bot ,.r"],
        [".top, .r", ".mid, .c", ".bot, .l"]
    ]; 
    $(".square").click(function(){ //to mark squares
        if ($(this).html() !== "") { //if square is not empty
            return;
        }
        if (movestate === true){
            move = "X";
            movestate = false;
        }
        else {
            move = "O";
            movestate = true;
        }
        $(this).html(move); //mark square
        for (var i = 0; i < winCondition.length; i++) { 
            if ($(winCondition[0]).innerText  == "") {
                    return;
            }           
             if (($(winCondition[i][0]).innerText == $(winCondition[i][1]).innerText) && ($(winCondition[i][0]).innerText == $(winCondition[i][2]).innerText)) {
            // check to see if game is won
                alert($(winCondition[i][0]).innerText+" wins!");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype=html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Three in a Row</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="../jquery/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javatoe2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "board">
        <div id="t1" class="square top l"></div>
        <div id="t2" class="square top c"></div>
        <div id="t3" class="square top r"></div>
        <div id="m1" class="square mid l"></div>
        <div id="m2" class="square mid c"></div>
        <div id="m3" class="square mid r"></div>
        <div id="b1" class="square bot l"></div>
        <div id="b2" class="square bot c"></div>
        <div id="b3" class="square bot r"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:
For future seekers, here is the code that now works -

```
<!doctype=html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Three in a Row</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="../jquery/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javatoe.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "board">
        <div id="t1" class="1 square top l"></div>
        <div id="t2" class="2 square top c"></div>
        <div id="t3" class="3 square top r"></div>
        <div id="m1" class="4 square mid l"></div>
        <div id="m2" class="5 square mid c"></div>
        <div id="m3" class="6 square mid r"></div>
        <div id="b1" class="7 square bot l"></div>
        <div id="b2" class="8 square bot c"></div>
        <div id="b3" class="9 square bot r"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

- 

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var move = "X",
        movestate = true,
        winCondition = [ 
        [".1", ".2", ".3"],
        [".4", ".5", ".6"],
        [".7", ".8", ".9"],
        [".1", ".4", ".7"],
        [".2", ".5", ".8"],
        [".3", ".6", ".9"],
        [".1", ".5", ".9"],
        [".3", ".5", ".7"]
    ]; 
    $(".square").click(function(){ //to mark squares
        if ($(this).html() !== "") { //if square is not empty
            return;
        }
        if (movestate === true){
            move = "X";
            movestate = false;
        }
        else {
            move = "O";
            movestate = true;
        }
        $(this).html(move); //mark square
        for (var i = 0; i < winCondition.length; i++) {
            if ($(winCondition[i][0]).text()  == "") {
                continue;
            }
                        if (($(winCondition[i][0])[0].innerText == $(winCondition[i][1])[0].innerText) 
                            && ($(winCondition[i][0])[0].innerText == $(winCondition[i][2])[0].innerText)) {
                        // check to see if game is won
                        alert($(winCondition[i][0])[0].innerText+" wins!");
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: In the code you have posted, you have `three.length`, but `three` is not defined.

Comment: Ahh, sorry. I used to have >three = winCondition[i] but I figured it might be cleaner to have fewer variables. I'll edit it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has a several problems.

(1) `.innerText` is a property of a DOM element, not a jquery object. You could use the following:

```
$(winCondition[i][0])[0].innerText
```

Or better, you could use the jquery `.text()` function, which gets the text from the body of an element.

```
$(winCondition[i][0]).text()
```

(2) Even with the change above, there is still a problem. When you do `$(winCondition[i][0])`, you are sometimes matching multiple elements. If you then call `$(winCondition[i][0]).text()`, it would get the combined text, which is not what you want. You could fix this by making all the selectors reference both a vertical class and a horizontal class.

(3) Selectors like `".top, .l"` do not match what you want. That selector matches all elements with the "top" class *plus* all elements with the "l" class. You want `".top.l"`, which matches only elements with both classes.

(4) For the following line of code:

```
if ($(winCondition[0]).innerText  == "") {
```

`winCondition[0]` is an array of strings. Perhaps you meant to have `winCondition[i][0]`.

(5) If you want to skip to the next iteration of a for-loop, use `continue`, not `return`.

Comment: You sir, are a gentleman and a scholar. Your proposed solutions worked perfectly, and I tip my hat at you. I appreciate the thorough and understandable explanation.

Making the selectors reference a vertical and horizontal class was something I should have done long ago.

Comment: @Jester - I hope you don't mind, but this seemed like a fun project, so [I made my own](http://jsfiddle.net/john_s/Bq97M/). If you look at the code, the win-condition selectors and the logic to check for a winner can be simpler than what you have.

Comment: That's pretty sweet. I was struggling a bit with the most efficient way to check for wins, then I decided to just pick a path and make it work. I definitely don't mind. In fact, I appreciate the lesson. Thanks again!